# NSPredicate with regEx, returns wrong result

Tags: swift, regex

I wrote the following regular expression to validate usernames:

`/^[a-zA-Z0-9\\._]+$/`

However, when I try to use it, something messes up, since it gives me the wrong result. The input I tried is the same as my SO handle: `ilikecode`. This is how I apply the regex:

```
let regex = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9\\._]+$/"
let usernameTest = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", regex)
print("username is valid", usernameTest.evaluate(with: username), username)
```

However, the regex always returns false.

Does anybody know how this is possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't enclose the pattern in `/.../`

Comment: @MartinR haha jesus, that took me 30 minutes... Can you make this an answer? I'd love to accept!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In some languages `/.../` is used to delimit a regular expression
pattern, separating the pattern from an action and the options,
for example

```
if ($userName =~ m/^[a-zA-Z0-9\\._]+$/i)
```

in Perl. But `NSPredicate` (or `NSRegularExpression`) take just a pattern
as argument, without enclosing slashes.

Also the anchors are implicit for the `MATCHES` operator, and
the `[c]` option can be used to specify case-insensitive matching:

```
let regex = "[a-z0-9\\._]+"
let usernameTest = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES[c] %@", regex)
```

Comment: *is used to define a regular expression* is not quite precise. The `/`s are regex delimiters that separate *action* from *pattern* from *options*. Since there are special methods for regex manipulations in Swift, there is no need in actions (like `m` for *matching*, or  `s` for *replacing*). There is no need in options, since you can specify them using flags, or as inline options (`(?i)` to make it case insensitive, or `(?m)` to make `^` / `$` match start/end of lines).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: You are right (of course)!